# Apache mod_rewrite stopped working when upgrading to 2.4.18

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4.18(Unix) on OS X.

It is interesting that this configuration works on Apache 2.2.15

I am attempting to access /foo/local on the domain, which I want rewritten to /index.php/foo/local.

The problem that I have is that inside the web root there is a foo.php file, and apache seems to only want to send traffic to /foo.php/local.

Is this something I have configured incorrectly in apache?

My rewrite rule is as follows:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The apache configuration for the web root is:

```
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I have done some initial debug and found that REQUEST_FILENAME for /foo/local is /path/to/webroot/foo.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's being caused by `MultiViews`.

`MultiViews` causes a request for `foo` to initiate a search for any file starting with `foo.` which the browser might be able to understand. When it finds `foo.php`, that gets served.

Just remove that from your configuration.